# Recursive function returning none?

Tags: python, recursion

I wrote the following function in order to implement my own binary search

```
def bisect(input, target):
    mid = len(input)/ 2
    if len(input) == 1:
        if input[0] == target:
            return 1
        else:
            return None
    elif input[mid] > target:
        bisect(input[:mid], target)
    elif input[mid] <= target:
        bisect(input[mid:], target)
```

I know my implementation is off, but I am more curious in understanding the recursive stack here.

When I call `bisect(['d','e'], 'd')`, my function should return the value of

```
bisect(['d'], 'd')
```

but instead it returns None. Further, when I call     `bisect(['d'], 'd')`directly, I get the correct value of 0. How is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are ignoring the return values of recursive calls. You need to *explicitly* return those too:

```
elif input[mid] > target:
    return bisect(input[:mid], target)
elif input[mid] <= target:
    return bisect(input[mid:], target)
```

Recursive calls are just like any other function call; they return a result to the caller. If you ignore the return value and the calling function then ends, you end up with that calling function then returning `None` instead.